# RaspberryPi rpi-firmware and .kos in buildroot package

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, raspberry-pi, buildroot

I am trying to bring up the kernel and RFS generated by buildroot on a Raspberry Pi board. I am able to bring up the minimal kernel and access shell via a serial cable.

I could see some .ko files that looks like peripheral drivers rpi-firmware package that is downloaded by buildroot. Is it possible to integrate those into the kernel image ? if so , how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I just have to enable the required drivers from the linux configuration menu (`make linux-menuconfig`) .

If I enable them as modules, they will be copied into a folder in /lib. Otherwise, they will be integrated in the zImage